# NPS RADIUS authentication fails due to user account

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, radius, nps

We're in the process of migrating our wireless network, adding in 802.11x-based RADIUS authentication. The set up is as follows:

1. Client connects to router01
2. Client authenticates through RADIUS on a Windows Server
3. Client should get connected (.. or not, depends on the credentials :P)

So this is what happens. All but Windows 7 clients connect succesfully. Count in iPhones, iPads, Macbooks and Windows 8 clients. When trying to connect to the wireless network from a Windows 7 client, which is joined to the domain, authentication seems to fail. The clients reports that there is a "problem with user account", even though it's the same user account as used on working clients. The following gets logged at the NPS side of things:

```
"WIN01","IAS",12/28/2014,20:32:03,1,"User@DOMAIN.local","DOMAIN\User","00-0C-F6-E2-EB-61","70-F3-95-E6-C0-26",,,"AP1","10.1.0.1",0,0,"10.1.0.1","router01",,,19,,,,5,"Secure Wireless Connections",0,"311 1 10.1.0.5 12/28/2014 18:36:12 349",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Secure Wireless Connections",1,,,,
"WIN01","IAS",12/28/2014,20:32:03,11,,"DOMAIN\User",,,,,,,,0,"10.1.0.1","router01",,,,,,,5,"Secure Wireless Connections",0,"311 1 10.1.0.5 12/28/2014 18:36:12 349",60,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Secure Wireless Connections",1,,,,
"WIN01","IAS",12/28/2014,20:32:04,1,"User@DOMAIN.local","DOMAIN\User","00-0C-F6-E2-EB-61","70-F3-95-E6-C0-26",,,"AP1","10.1.0.1",0,0,"10.1.0.1","router01",,,19,,,,5,"Secure Wireless Connections",0,"311 1 10.1.0.5 12/28/2014 18:36:12 350",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Secure Wireless Connections",1,,,,
"WIN01","IAS",12/28/2014,20:32:04,11,,"DOMAIN\User",,,,,,,,0,"10.1.0.1","router01",,,,,,,5,"Secure Wireless Connections",0,"311 1 10.1.0.5 12/28/2014 18:36:12 350",30,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Secure Wireless Connections",1,,,,
"WIN01","IAS",12/28/2014,20:32:05,1,"User@DOMAIN.local","DOMAIN\User","00-0C-F6-E2-EB-61","70-F3-95-E6-C0-26",,,"AP1","10.1.0.1",0,0,"10.1.0.1","router01",,,19,,,,5,"Secure Wireless Connections",0,"311 1 10.1.0.5 12/28/2014 18:36:12 351",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Secure Wireless Connections",1,,,,
"WIN01","IAS",12/28/2014,20:32:05,11,,"DOMAIN\User",,,,,,,,0,"10.1.0.1","router01",,,,,,,5,"Secure Wireless Connections",0,"311 1 10.1.0.5 12/28/2014 18:36:12 351",30,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Secure Wireless Connections",1,,,,
"WIN01","IAS",12/28/2014,20:32:05,1,"User@DOMAIN.local","DOMAIN\User","00-0C-F6-E2-EB-61","70-F3-95-E6-C0-26",,,"AP1","10.1.0.1",0,0,"10.1.0.1","router01",,,19,,,,5,"Secure Wireless Connections",0,"311 1 10.1.0.5 12/28/2014 18:36:12 352",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Secure Wireless Connections",1,,,,
"WIN01","IAS",12/28/2014,20:32:05,11,,"DOMAIN\User",,,,,,,,0,"10.1.0.1","router01",,,,,,,5,"Secure Wireless Connections",0,"311 1 10.1.0.5 12/28/2014 18:36:12 352",30,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Secure Wireless Connections",1,,,,
"WIN01","IAS",12/28/2014,20:32:05,1,"User@DOMAIN.local","DOMAIN\User","00-0C-F6-E2-EB-61","70-F3-95-E6-C0-26",,,"AP1","10.1.0.1",0,0,"10.1.0.1","router01",,,19,,,,5,"Secure Wireless Connections",0,"311 1 10.1.0.5 12/28/2014 18:36:12 353",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Secure Wireless Connections",1,,,,
"WIN01","IAS",12/28/2014,20:32:05,11,,"DOMAIN\User",,,,,,,,0,"10.1.0.1","router01",,,,,,,5,"Secure Wireless Connections",0,"311 1 10.1.0.5 12/28/2014 18:36:12 353",30,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Secure Wireless Connections",1,,,,
"WIN01","IAS",12/28/2014,20:32:07,1,"User@DOMAIN.local","DOMAIN\User","00-0C-F6-E2-EB-61","70-F3-95-E6-C0-26",,,"AP1","10.1.0.1",0,0,"10.1.0.1","router01",,,19,,,,5,"Secure Wireless Connections",0,"311 1 10.1.0.5 12/28/2014 18:36:12 354",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Secure Wireless Connections",1,,,,
"WIN01","IAS",12/28/2014,20:32:07,11,,"DOMAIN\User",,,,,,,,0,"10.1.0.1","router01",,,,,,,5,"Secure Wireless Connections",0,"311 1 10.1.0.5 12/28/2014 18:36:12 354",60,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Secure Wireless Connections",1,,,,
"WIN01","IAS",12/28/2014,20:32:07,1,"User@DOMAIN.local","DOMAIN\User","00-0C-F6-E2-EB-61","70-F3-95-E6-C0-26",,,"AP1","10.1.0.1",0,0,"10.1.0.1","router01",,,19,,,,5,"Secure Wireless Connections",0,"311 1 10.1.0.5 12/28/2014 18:36:12 355",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Secure Wireless Connections",1,,,,
"WIN01","IAS",12/28/2014,20:32:07,11,,"DOMAIN\User",,,,,,,,0,"10.1.0.1","router01",,,,,,,5,"Secure Wireless Connections",0,"311 1 10.1.0.5 12/28/2014 18:36:12 355",30,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Secure Wireless Connections",1,,,,
"WIN01","IAS",12/28/2014,20:32:07,1,"User@DOMAIN.local","DOMAIN\User","00-0C-F6-E2-EB-61","70-F3-95-E6-C0-26",,,"AP1","10.1.0.1",0,0,"10.1.0.1","router01",,,19,,,,5,"Secure Wireless Connections",0,"311 1 10.1.0.5 12/28/2014 18:36:12 356",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Secure Wireless Connections",1,,,,
"WIN01","IAS",12/28/2014,20:32:07,11,,"DOMAIN\TestUser",,,,,,,,0,"10.1.0.1","router01",,,,,,,5,"Secure Wireless Connections",0,"311 1 10.1.0.5 12/28/2014 18:36:12 356",30,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Secure Wireless Connections",1,,,,
"WIN01","IAS",12/28/2014,20:32:08,1,"User@DOMAIN.local","DOMAIN\User","00-0C-F6-E2-EB-61","70-F3-95-E6-C0-26",,,"AP1","10.1.0.1",0,0,"10.1.0.1","router01",,,19,,,,5,"Secure Wireless Connections",0,"311 1 10.1.0.5 12/28/2014 18:36:12 357",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Secure Wireless Connections",1,,,,
"WIN01","IAS",12/28/2014,20:32:08,11,,"DOMAIN\User",,,,,,,,0,"10.1.0.1","router01",,,,,,,5,"Secure Wireless Connections",0,"311 1 10.1.0.5 12/28/2014 18:36:12 357",30,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Secure Wireless Connections",1,,,,
"WIN01","IAS",12/28/2014,20:32:08,1,"User@DOMAIN.local","DOMAIN\User","00-0C-F6-E2-EB-61","70-F3-95-E6-C0-26",,,"AP1","10.1.0.1",0,0,"10.1.0.1","router01",,,19,,,,5,"Secure Wireless Connections",0,"311 1 10.1.0.5 12/28/2014 18:36:12 358",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Secure Wireless Connections",1,,,,
"WIN01","IAS",12/28/2014,20:32:08,11,,"DOMAIN\User",,,,,,,,0,"10.1.0.1","router01",,,,,,,5,"Secure Wireless Connections",0,"311 1 10.1.0.5 12/28/2014 18:36:12 358",30,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Secure Wireless Connections",1,,,,
```

I should also mention that, when connecting through one of the working clients, events are generated into the Windows Event Log - no matter wether the credentials are right or not. The Windows 7 PCs don't create a log entry in the Event Log, making me believe that they don't even get past authenticating themselves.

Comment: +1
i exactly same issue.
have found a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately we have not found a solution to this specific problem as of yet.